# Automate tests with MFA

Tags: automated-tests, multi-factor-authentication

We would like to automate our integration tests, which require MFA with SMS as part of the login.
In order to do so, we would like to register with a constant number, login, and read the SMS code that was received to the number by API.

With which application can this be done?
Google Voice is available only for US numbers.